# Tensorflow: Weird broadcasting behavior

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I did not quite well understand how the broadcasting mechanism works in Tensorflow. Assume that we have the following code:

```
W1_shape = [5, 5, 1, 32]
b1_shape = [32]
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
initial_W1 = tf.truncated_normal(shape=W1_shape, stddev=0.1)
W1 = tf.Variable(initial_W1)
initial_b1 = tf.constant(0.1, shape=b1_shape)
b1 = tf.Variable(initial_b1)
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
conv1_sum = conv1 + b1
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = conv1 + y

sess = tf.Session()
# Run init ops
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

while True:
    samples, labels, indices = dataset.get_next_batch(batch_size=1000)
    samples = samples.reshape((1000, MnistDataSet.MNIST_SIZE, MnistDataSet.MNIST_SIZE, 1))
    y_data = np.ones(shape=(1000, 32))
    conv1_res, conv1_sum_res, b1_res, z_res=\
    sess.run([conv1, conv1_sum, b1, z], feed_dict={x: samples, y: y_data})

if dataset.isNewEpoch:
    break
```

So, I load the MNIST dataset, which consists of 28x28 sized images. The convolution operator uses 32 filters of 5x5 size. I use a batch size of 1000, so data tensor `x` has the shape (1000,28,28,1). The `tf.nn.conv2d` operation outputs a tensor of the shape (1000,28,28,32). `y` is a placeholder, a variable which I add to check Tensorflow's broadcasting mechanism by adding it to (1000,28,28,32) shaped `conv1` tensor. In the line `y_data = np.ones(shape=(1000, 32))`, I experiment with various tensor shapes for `y`. The shapes (28,28), (1000,28) and (1000,32) won't add to `conv1`, with the errors of the type:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [1000,28,28,32] vs. [28,28]

The shapes (28,32) and (28,28,32) work and broadcast correctly. But according to the broadcasting semantics explained in https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting , the first three shapes have to work as well, since they are of the correct order by matching dimensions with the 4D `conv1` tensor. For example, (28,28) matches (1000,28,28,32) in the dimensions 1 and 2, (1000,32) matches in the dimensions 0 and 3, just as mentioned in the link. Am I missing or misunderstanding something here? What is the correct broadcasting behavior of Tensorflow in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its true the documentation seems to be suggesting what you say. But it looks like it follows `numpy broadcsting rules`:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
>   element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its
>   way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when :
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

So by the above definition:

- (28, 28) cannot broadcast to (1000, 28, 28, 32) but (28, 28, 1) can be.
- (1000,28) cannot but (1000, 1, 28, 1) or (1000, 28, 1, 1) can
- (28, 32) works because the trailing dimensions match.

Comment: Yes it really seems that way. The documentation is scarily incorrect on broadcasting.